# Delete DB row on back end with <a href></a> on front end

Tags: php, html

I have a row of links like this:

`Delete |  Votes (2) | Comments (1)`

They are each associated with user posts.

My question is on `Delete`:

All I want user to do is click it and then this needs to happen on php side:

```
<?php
    $reviewId = $database -> escape_value(trim($_POST['reviewId']));
    $user_id = $database -> escape_value(trim($_POST['user_id']));
    // Delete Review Method    
    $result = Data::deleteMyReview($reviewId);
?>
```

My questions, what is the most efficient way of writing the code for Delete?

I don't really want an entire form for that one word.  But then it also seems like a security issue to continue with the `<a href="thispage.php?reviewId=1&userId=1">Delete</a>` approach.  Then anyone can delete user comment by altering the url.

So should I use `Post` vs `Get` and `Form` vs `<a>`?

Comment: You should definitely **NOT** be using regular links for a delete operation: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: In either case, if all you are using is the informations sent from the browser, `POST` or `GET` won't make as much of a difference since the data is exposed either way (but a bit more obscured by using `POST` through a form or javascript ajax post). You should be using something server-side to verify that the user has rights to perform the delete in the first place (e.g. `SESSION`)

Comment: @BrendanBullen  The delete button only shows up for comments with a user_id associated with the logged in user_id `Session` variable.  If that is what you mean...  If that is secure enough, it seems like `POST` is way to go.  Then my question remains on how to optimize the code - an entire `form` for a single word?

Comment: @KickingLettuce You should STILL verify the delete action after the data has been submitted (i.e wrap your delete code in another session check). But yes, `POST` would be the way to go for the client side code.

Comment: I guess if I am looking for clean code to do this, I should just learn AJAX. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using a form with the `post` method seems more appropriate for a delete action. I would have a separate form for each row, containing a hidden input with the ID and a submit button. A single form would work but you would have to have some Javascript to set the ID when each button is clicked.

A form is no more secure than a link. To make either way secure, you need to verify that the current user is authorized to delete the target review. For example, check that he owns the review. This should be done right before the delete code is executed.

It's fine to hide the delete button for reviews that don't belong to the user, but you should not rely on that for security because anyone can post a form and set the review ID to delete, regardless of what you were hiding and showing on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `<a>` element and still POST the data. For example, using jQuery to perform an AJAX post:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="delete-review" data-review-id="123" data-user-id="123">Delete</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete-review').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "thispage.php",
            data: { reviewId: $(this).data('review-id'), userId: $(this).data('user-id') },
            success: function(data) {
                //Do whatever you want to do when the delete succeeds such as redirect to another page
            },
            error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                //Handle your error here
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

As stated in my comments, for security concerns, you definitely need to validate the data before performing the delete. Don't trust it just because the delete option should only been seen by a valid user and you're using `POST`. Always validate.